# Where to Find or Develop a Low Latency/Delay Livestream Service

Tags: delay, live-streaming, firewire

I have been using Ustream for a small adult education startup for about a year now. Great service and all, but the delay to end user is become unacceptable. It's about 25-30 seconds.

My plan is to have a embedded player and "live talk" window developed on a secure part of our website where distance-learning participants (about 50% of our students) can talk live to the lecturer being recorded.

Our setup is pretty conventional: one consumer video camera fed to my PC via Firewire 800 using Ustream Producer (really a white-labeled version of Telestream Wirecast) and out to the Ustream server.

Where can I find or create a livestream/video stream mechanism with little delay (3-5 seconds max)? Will a dedicated server be needed for this? Adobe Media Server?

Answer (score 0):

UStream is a live streaming service.  With most if not all live streaming providers the emphasis is on using a longer latency to increase the video quality.
What you are looking for is a video conferencing or video chat application. There are plenty of commercial services offering those or you can set up you own server.
Adobe FMS, Wowza or Red5 are Flash servers that you can use for that.
You then need a Flash application to run in the user's browser, some example of how to do that are:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/first_im_app.html
http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.6.0/examples/VideoChat/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html
http://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/